# block divs height ingnored

Tags: html, css

I have one div style

```
.metal_rods{        
    max-width:200px;
    background:red; 
    margin:1px;
    display:block;
}
```

And here are the divs

```
<div class='metal_rods' height='10px'> 50 </div> 
<div class='metal_rods' height='110px'> 50 </div> 
<div class='metal_rods' height='90px'> 50 </div> 
<div class='metal_rods' height='0'> 50 </div>
```

even when the divs have different heights, then appear the same for some reason. 
even with display changed to `inline-block`

here is a demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/KfDm9/

I know I am missing something easy, but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `height` attribute, that's out like disco.

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT** `height` is DEAD like disco. It's not valid, don't use. Ever. If you used in the past, build a time machine, and undo it.

Use CSS only:

```
<div class='metal_rods' style="height:10px;"> 50 </div> 
<div class='metal_rods' style="height:110px"> 50 </div> 
<div class='metal_rods' style="height:90px'> 50 </div> 
<div class='metal_rods' style="height:0"'> 50 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KfDm9/2/

Also, move those style attributes to a separate CSS file, it's bad form to write them inline on your elements. Do you really want to force all devices to style the elements the same way? A separate CSS stylesheet for different mediums means you can style elements differently depending on the medium and resolution! You can have different styles for browsers, printers, tablets, smartphones, and things that haven't even been invented yet.

Comment: It's not only "out", it was never "in" for a `div`.  Images can have a `height` attribute, not a `div`.

Comment: 2 years working with HTMl, and I have never known this before. thanks.

Comment: Also check my last paragraph I just updated, please.

Comment: Thanks. I know the difference b/n inline/external css declarations. I just wanted to use the height attribute in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do `height='value'` it's an attribute that has no meaning for a DIV.

Do a `style='height:value'` instead